# understanding load balancing in iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have inherited this environment which has a linux server as a router and it's routing traffic to two servers.

```
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW statistic mode nth every 2 to:192.168.xx.32:443
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW statistic mode nth every 1 to:192.168.xx.33:443
```

I have done some researching and I'm have trouble understanding `statistic mode nth every 2` means?

What I have read is that `nth every 2` is basically a counter, for examples, once it hits 
`nth every 2` the counter resets.

So, how it traffic being distributed in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

iptables `statistic` module with `nth` mode does exactly what you said: it will match every N'th packet and perform an action based on that match, which in this case is to replace the destination to that specified in `to:`.

Assuming you are using an older kernel, the two lines may match round-robin, but without knowing your kernel version or the details behind the iptable version, it's hard to say.

Check `man 8 iptables-extensions` for details.